# How to add google play services in IntelliJ IDEA 13 with gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, google-play-services

I want to add the google play service to my project with gradle but every time I try to build/ run I get the following error:

> Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':BPA App'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':BPA App:_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42.
> >          Required by:
> >              BPA App:BPA App:unspecified

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
//    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }

}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
}
```

Of course I have installed google repository and other things from the SDK-Manager.

The support-v4 and support-v7 libs works fine.

I´m new in builds with gradle. Before gradle I have imported the service-lib as a module and everything works.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you download it in your sdk manager?

Comment: Sure, it works in my IDE without gradle as a Module Lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several things going on here:

- You don't have installed the **Google Play Services** extra from the *SDK Manager*. So you can go there and install it. (Not just Google Repository, but **Google Play Services** itself)
- If you got the extra installed, but Studio doesn't recognize it, maybe you're pinpointing the wrong SDK. It happens that Android Studio had its own pre-bundled SDK, so, if you got another one installed on your computer, you may be installing the extras in that one, and AS is triying to build with the one that has not the extras installed.

Check it out in Files>ProjectStructure and make sure you got the right SDK.

Comment: I´ve checked everything. I have both SDK (Android Studio and "normal"). And both SDKs have the latest version of google play services. In the ProjectStructure I´m pointing the "normal" SDK. And of course there is the latest version of google play services. Also my ANDROID_HOME is pointing to the "normal" Android SDK"C:\development\android-sdk".

Comment: Mmm, check the local.properties in your application root folder, it should include a _sdk.dir_ variable with a value. Check if that value points to your normal SDK. If this doesn't help, could you please post your entire build.grade file here? It'll help me understand better if I see the entire picture.

Comment: sdk.dir=C\:\\development\\android-sdk (normal one)
 Will update build.gradle file.

Comment: Try creating a new project with AS 0.5. I noticed you are using an old version of the Gradle Plugin, use 0.9.+ instead. Creating a new project should use the last one, and try adding PlayServices there. If you still getting errors, go to C\:\\development\\android-sdk and run the android program to double check you got Google Play Services extra installed in that particular SDK. Also, in the SDK Manager, check if you got installed the last version of a tool called Android SDK Build Tool. I none of it works for you, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I found the solution! It was of course my fault. I´ve install all extras of the SDK Manager and now it works! I think I confused "Android Support Repository" with "Google Repository"! Thx you guys for helping me!!!

Answer (score 0):

To get play services I usually go for:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'`

This will give you the latest variant of 4.2 (i.e. *4.2.highest available incremental version*)

---

Move `mavenCentral()` to the top, dependencies are resolved in top down order, if that still fails remove `maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }` as a test

Comment: Don´t work for me. I´ve also tried lower version without any result.

Comment: removed the other repository and try but no effect. Still the same problem.

Comment: maybe now you have removed the other repo you need to do `--refresh-dependencies`

Comment: I´ve refreshed it. Still no result.

Comment: I have also tried Android Studio (V0.5.0) and on an other computer. But still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is not the best practice not to mention the version of the compiled code but if you do not want to update your dependency section each time you update your google play services (using SDK manager), just put this reference in your dependency section:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```